# MongoDB Index for both int and text

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have this query:

```
{
 branchId: 23,
 Name:  /.*ABC.*/i
}
```

I created index

```
{
branchId: 1,
Name: 1
}
```

I can see branchId scan for the index, but Name not, how can I make this query faster?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have regex and it is not a `prefix expression` and it is case insensitive, thus index is not used.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)

You can try using text index. But there are other restrictions when using text index.

> Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively.